# antd 3.26.19 mapPropsToFields and Form validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, antd

The antd website has the following code example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/hx459?file=/index.js

In documentation for the mapPropsToFields function it is written:
`Please note that the form fields will become controlled components. Properties like errors will not be automatically mapped and need to be manually passed in.`

The above example uses the mapPropsToFields function.
Please explain why form field validation works.
(how errors manually passed in)